# cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan()は非同期処理でしょうか？

Tags: typescript, cordova, angular2

cordova cli ver.10.0.0, Angular2で開発しています。

`cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan` 処理を以下のソースを実装して実行してみると、以下の順番でメッセージが表示されています。

・readCodeCtrl start
・Scan Result :
・scan success!

`CodeScannerCtrl` 処理で`scanCode`を呼び出す時、`scanCode`の実施を持たず、次の処理を続いて実施するようです。
`barcodeScanner`はデバイスのカメラを利用してユーザのレスポンスを求める処理であり、非同期処理ではないと思いますが、かえって今非同期処理のように行われているようです。`cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan`は非同期処理でしょうか？参照できる資料などがございましたら、教えていただけますようお願い申し上げます。

```
CodeScannerCtrl(scanResult) {
    alert("readCodeCtrl start");
    this.scanCode(scanResult);
    alert("Scan Result : " + scanResult);
}

ScanCode(scanResult) {
   cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
            (result) => {
               alert("scan success!");},
            (error) => {
               alert("scan failed!");},
            {
                preferFrontCamera: false,
                .
                .
                .
                .
            }
   );
}
```